# The Code below is Working fine, The problem is i'm Unable change the focus on the page to the Case Detail Subtab

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, console, lightning-tabfocused

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/42.0/integration.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    function testOpenSubtab() {
        //First find the ID of the primary tab to put the new subtab in
           sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
         console.log('openSubtab'+openSubtab);

    }

    var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
        //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can open a new subtab in it
        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        console.log('result.id'+result.id);
        console.log('primaryTabId '+primaryTabId);
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'www.google.com', false, 
        'Order App',null);
        console.log('**  openSubtab : '+openSubtab);

    };

 function setFocusSubTab(){
    sforce.console.getSubtabIds(focusSubTab);
}

var focusSubTab = function focusSubTab(result){
    sforce.console.focusSubtabById(result);
};
```

sforce.console.focusSubtabById(previousOnload);
     var previousOnload = window.onload;
        // Script runs automatically when page is finished loading
        window.onload = function(result) {
            if (previousOnload) {
                sforce.console.setTabTitle('Case:'+'{!Case.CaseNumber}');
                setFocusSubTab();
            }

```
    }

    testOpenSubtab();
</script>

<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:form >
        <body >
           <apex:detail subject="{!case.Id}" />

        </body>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. To be productive here, you need to include more than a title and a large code paste. What *exactly* is not working in your code? Which lines? What errors are shown, or what bad behavior? Consider including only *relevant* code, not everything. [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good resource to learn how to frame a successful, answerable question.

Comment: Thank you! Code is working fine but the problem is it has two subtabs,i need to set the focus  onto first tab but it is always changing the focus to the second tab.

Answer (score 1):

Merge fields generally need to be in quotes:

```
var caseid = "{!case.id}";
```

As an aside, you can use merge fields directly in a string:

```
sforce.console.setTabTitle('Case: {!Case.CaseNumber}');
```

You should always consider what the JavaScript source would look like *as if* the merge field were literally replaced in to the source (which is what happens).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but it was working fine  the single quotes as well,the problem is i'm unable  to set the focus on tab1 .

Comment: @SalesforceUser Why not? Are you getting an error? Without more details, we can only go on what you've given us, which was already-broken code.

Comment: No error, Actually it's not changing the tab sforce.console.focusSubtabById(openSubtab); so i've written the function function testFocusSubtabById() {
            //Get the value for 'scc-st-0' from the openSubtab method
            //This value is for example purposes only
                      console.log('*subtabId tabid:'+subtabId);
            sforce.console.focusSubtabById(subtabId);
        } and on page load I've called the method when i do that its not opening the subtab sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'www.google.com', true, 
            'Order App',null);

Comment: @SalesforceUser The callback should give you an error object as well. What does it say?

Comment: JavaScript Alert:Focus changed to a different subtab. The subtab Id is 'id of the tab'and the object Id is:null,  object Id is:null because subtab is opening the page google.com.sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'www.google.com', true, 'Order App',null); now i want the console to open Subtab case detail page.

Comment: @SalesforceUser Again, did you check the properties of "result"? Is there an error message?

Comment: Thank you for your comments,i've made some changes to the code it started working again.   sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'www.google.com', false,'Order App',null);
and 
   function setFocusSubTab(){
        sforce.console.getSubtabIds(focusSubTab);
    }

    var focusSubTab = function focusSubTab(result){
        sforce.console.focusSubtabById(result);
    };